# Is there any way to work with the database of variable but similar structure using strongly typed datasets?

Tags: c#, sql, gps, dataset, sql-server-2012

I work with GPS data which is stored in a SQL Server 2012 table with the following columns:

```
[Xcoord]  [Ycoord]  [time]  [speed]
```

There are already a lot of code that processes this data and based on strongly typed data set, table adapter and stored procedures.

But several manufacturers of GPS trackers provide additional information such as signals from opened/closed doors which are stored in additional columns, e.g. D1, D2, D3, D4 for each door accordingly. Some of customers needed this info and some of them not.

So each customer has their own database with GPS data table each of which has similar structure:

```
[Xcoord]  [Ycoord]  [time]  [speed]  [SignalColumn1] [SignalColumn2] [...]
```

Just for example several types of GPS data table structures:

```
[Xcoord]  [Ycoord]  [time]  [speed]  [D1]  [D2]  [D3]  [D4]  [D5]  [D6]

[Xcoord]  [Ycoord]  [time]  [speed]  [power_supply]  [fuel_level]
```

The task is to extend existing application which could connect to each type of databases, provide the same functionality and additionally processing signal columns if needed by the customer. Rewriting it using untyped dataset is VERY expensive. Creating new dataset for each table will lead to copy a lot of methods which is not good from the point of styling.

So the question is:

Is there any way to work with the database of variable but similar structure using strongly typed datasets?

Please provide your examples with C#.

P.S.
Processing means generating complex events with car using this data, for example define where the car was stopped or to determine if the car is inside the specific geographical zone determined by polygon or determine declination from the plan trajectory and so on. It is also useful to define logical operations with these complex events, for instance determine when the car was stopped AND the door was opened.

Answer (score 1):

Typed Datasets just have property wrappers around an untyped DataSet.  You could define a typed dataset with the common properties [Xcoord]  [Ycoord]  [time]  [speed] and still access the "extra" fields the untyped way, as long as your query pulls them down.   The classes that get generated are all partial so you could even create a matching class that is partial and add a common interface.

You could also make multiple typed datasets by hand that inherit from the common one and check if they have the "Extra" fields and wrap that dataset in the one you created by hand.

Without knowing how you want to access these extra fields it's hard to say which way is best.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of processing is being preformed, but of the top of my head I'd suggest a xml column to hold the variable data, with a different adapter for each client that would process that xml.

XML serialization could be handy there as well.

For more ideas please elaborate more about the processing being done.

Comment: Processing means generating complex events with car using this data, for example define where the car was stopped or to determine if the car is in the specific geographical zone determined by polygon or determine declination from the plan trajectory and so on.
It is also useful to define logical operations with these complex events, for instance determine when the car was stopped AND the door  was opened.

Comment: No matter which way you'll go (@CharlesNRice answer and mine are just two examples out of many possibilities) you're gonna have to write some adapters to handle the specific fields.  You can do it using some plugin architecture or by inheritance and factory methods.. But there is no need to copy the code that addresses the common data.